# React - правильный способ передать пропс в модалку

Tags: javascript, reactjs, modal

1. Есть стейт, хранящий состояние модалки (открыта/закрыта).
2. Есть две кнопки, которые по клику меняют состояние модалки на "октрыта".
3. Какой самый лучший способ внутри модалки понять, какая из кнопок была нажата?

Первое что приходит в голову - сделать дополнительный стейт, который будет хранить информацию о том, какая кнопка была нажата (и передавать эту информацию в модалку через пропс). А для кнопок сделать разные хендлеры, которые перед открытием модалки будут записывать в этот стейт, какая кнопка вызвала событие. Есть ли какой-то более изящный способ понять внутри модалки, какая кнопка вызвала событие открытия?

```
const [modalOpen, setModalOpen] = useState(false)

const clickHandler = () => {
    setModalOpen(true)
}

<Button onClick={clickHandler} />

<Button2 onClick={clickHandler} />

<Modal active={modalOpen}>
```

Comment: а зачем модалке понимать какая кнопка была нажата?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ваш подход с использованием дополнительного состояния для отслеживания того, какая кнопка была нажата, является вполне разумным. Однако, если вы хотите избежать создания дополнительного состояния, вы можете передавать информацию о кнопке непосредственно в обработчик событий.

Вместо использования одного и того же обработчика событий для обеих кнопок, вы можете создать два разных обработчика, которые передают различные значения в функцию setModalOpen. Затем вы можете использовать это значение внутри модалки для определения, какая кнопка была нажата.

Вот пример того, как это может выглядеть:

```js
const [modalOpen, setModalOpen] = useState(null)

const clickHandler1 = () => {
    setModalOpen('button1')
}

const clickHandler2 = () => {
    setModalOpen('button2')
}

<Button onClick={clickHandler1} />

<Button2 onClick={clickHandler2} />

<Modal active={modalOpen !== null} button={modalOpen} />
```

В этом примере, modalOpen теперь хранит строку, указывающую на кнопку, которая была нажата, или null, если модалка закрыта. Модалка теперь принимает дополнительный проп button, который можно использовать для определения, какая кнопка была нажата.

Comment: обработчик может быть одинаковым для обеих кнопок, доступ к кнопкам есть внутри обработчика

Answer (score 1):

> Есть ли какой-то более изящный способ понять внутри модалки, какая кнопка вызвала событие открытия?

Про именно "изящество" не мне судить... Но предложу просто немного усложнить сам стейт и немного переделать функцию `clickHandler`.

```js
//
function Modal({active}) {
  if (!active.act) return null
  return <div>
    {active.info}
  </div>
}
//
function Button({onClick}) {
  return <button onClick={onClick('Информация о кнопке Button')}>Button</button>
}
//
function Button2({onClick}) {
  return <button onClick={onClick('Информация о кнопке Button2')}>Button 2</button>
}
//
function App() {
  const [modalOpen, setModalOpen] = React.useState({act: false, info: null})
  const clickHandler = info => () => {
    setModalOpen({act: true, info})
  }
  return <section>
    <Button onClick={clickHandler} />
    <Button2 onClick={clickHandler} />
    <Modal active={modalOpen} />
  </section>
}

const domContainer = document.querySelector('#like_button_container');
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(domContainer);
root.render(<App />);
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>
<div id="like_button_container"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Немного модифицированное решение с передачей информации о кнопке непосредственно в обработчик событий. Можно обойтись и 1 обработчиком, правильно передавая ему параметры.

*либо сразу в `onClick` в анонимной функции запускать `setModalOpen`
и props-ами ее в компоненте добавить*

```
onClick={ () => setModalOpen('Button2') }
```

*либо, чтобы иметь возможность вынести функцию и не цеплять каждый раз - использовать связывание `bind` с нужной переменной*

```
onClick={ handleModal.bind(null, 'Button1') }
```

```js
const Button = ({ onClick, title }) => {
    return (
      <button onClick={ onClick }>{title}</button>
    )
  }
  const Modal = ({button}) => {
    return (
      !!button
      ? <div data-button={button}>Модальное окно {button}</div>
      : ''
    )
  }

  function App() {
    const [modalOpen, setModalOpen] = React.useState('')

    const handleModal = (button) => {
      setModalOpen(button);
    }

    return (
      <div>
        <Button onClick={ handleModal.bind(null, 'Button1') } title="Button1"/>
        <Button onClick={ () => setModalOpen('Button2') } title="Button2" />
        <button onClick={ () => setModalOpen('') }>Закрыть</button>
        <Modal button={ modalOpen } />
      </div>
    )
  }
  
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <App />
);
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```